# Ordering rows based on cross reference between columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, order-by

I have a table like this:

```
Lat1  Lng1  Lat2  Lng2
----  ----  ----  ----
1     1     2     2
2     2     5     5
3     3     4     4
4     4     3     3
5     5     4     4
```

Is it possible to return the rows in the following order?

```
Lat1  Lng1  Lat2  Lng2
----  ----  ----  ----
1     1     2     2
2     2     5     5
5     5     4     4
4     4     3     3
3     3     4     4
```

There is a unique `rowid` column.

The `(Lat1,Lng1)` and `(Lat2,Lng2)` pairs will always be unique.

`lat1` and `long1` of row `n+1` must be the same as `lat2` and `long2` of row `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a hierarchical recursive CTE.

The only problem is that you have a loop in your data, due to there being `3,3`,`4,4` and `4,4`, `3,3`.

```
drop table #tmp;

create table #tmp
(
lat1 int,
lng1 int,
lat2 int,
lng2 int
);

insert into #tmp values (1,1,2,2);
insert into #tmp values (2,2,5,5);
insert into #tmp values (3,3,4,4);
insert into #tmp values (4,4,3,3);
insert into #tmp values (5,5,4,4);

WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
   lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2,
    0 AS level, cast('('+cast(lat1 as varchar) + ',' + cast(lng1 as varchar)+')' as varchar) as path 
  FROM #tmp
  WHERE lat1=1 and lng1=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  t.lat1,t.lng1,t.lat2,t.lng2, 
  level+1, cast(path+','+'('+cast(t.lat2 as varchar) + ',' + cast(t.lng2 as varchar)+')' as varchar)
  FROM #tmp t
  INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.lat2 = t.lat1 and c.lng2 = t.lng1
)
select * from cte; 
;
```

The `WHERE lat1=1 and lng1=1` part specifies the base of the hierarchy (which is probably the start of a journey, in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Try my script with diff sample data.

I don't think you need `Recursive CTE` to do so.

It work in `Sql server 2012+`

```
create table #tmp
(
lat1 int,
lng1 int,
lat2 int,
lng2 int
);

insert into #tmp values (1,1,2,2);
insert into #tmp values (2,2,5,5);
insert into #tmp values (3,3,4,4);
insert into #tmp values (4,4,3,3);
insert into #tmp values (5,5,4,4);

;with CTE as
(
select t.lat1,t.lng1, t.lat2,t.lng2
,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select NULL))rn 
from #tmp t
)
select isnull(lag(lat2,1) over(order by rn),lat1)lat1,  
isnull(lag(lng2,1) over(order by rn),lng1)lng1,  
c.lat2,c.lng2
from cte c


drop table #tmp;
```

Also Note, `CTE` with `row_number` may or may not require in real life,depending upon real data.It is just for `ordering` purpose.